# Java sets- remove all

Tags: java, set

I have a method that takes in an array of strings.  My problem is with
the output: From the line to print `setOfArray` I get the following
output which is correct for `array`

```
(buy,pay,sell): [sell, pay] [sell]
[] [buy, sell] [buy] [buy, pay]
```

However this doesn't transfer into `mapOfPermissions`.

My output is:

```
{buy:pay:sell:=[buy, sell, pay],
pay:=[buy, sell, pay], pay:sell:=[buy, sell, pay], buy:=[buy, sell,
pay] . . . . }
```

Any ideas how I could fix this?

```
public Map build (String[] array){   
    setOfArray = new HashSet<String>();

    for (String a : array ){
        setOfArray.add(a);
    }

    Arrays.sort(array);
    int n = array.length; 
    String current = "";

    int i = 0;

    while ( i<n) {  

        for (int j = i ; j<n ; j++){    

            current = current + (array[j] + ":");   
            woSeed = new HashSet<String>();
            StringTokenizer stringtokenizer = new StringTokenizer(current, ":");
            while (stringtokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {

                woSeed.add(stringtokenizer.nextToken());

            }

            setOfArray.removeAll(woSeed);

            System.out.println(setOfArray);
            mapOfPermissions.put(current,setOfArray);

            for (String a : array ){

                setOfArray.add(a);
            }       
        }   
        current = "";
        i++;            
    }
    return mapOfPermissions;
}
```

thanks

Comment: What is input to `build` method and what is expected output?

Comment: Input: buy, pay, sell

Comment: Output: buy:pay:sell:=[ ], pay:sell = [buy] etc Basically the set should contain everything but the values in the name. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Please **edit** your question, and fix the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/243725).

Comment: Not related to the question, but if you append to a string multiple times in a loop you can improve the performance by using a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the below line:

`mapOfPermissions.put(current,setOfArray);`

Basically, we are putting the values in the map, however, we still have the reference (i.e. `setOfArray`) and hence, when we `add/remove` elements using that reference, the value in the map gets changed. The solution is to use the below line instead:

`mapOfPermissions.put(current,new HashSet<String>(setOfArray));`

This puts a copy of the set into map and hence, further changes in that set don't affect the map value.